# Javascript variable has different value in anonymous callback

Tags: javascript, callback, scope, closures

I came across this bug and didn't find an example anywhere.  Documenting here for reference.

The problem was that when calling `o.callback()` in the example below, the value of `x` changes between defining and executing the callback.

```
p = {
    f: function () { x = 'p.f() local'; }
};
o = {
    f: function () {
        x = 'o.f() local';
        this.callback = function () { console.log(x); };
    }
};
o.f();
p.f();
o.callback.apply();
```

The output here is:

```
p.f() local
```

While I expected:

```
o.f() local
```

**Update**
Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/elplatt/kzS5A/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed by using `var` to define x

```
var x = 'o.f() local'
```

The `x` in both `o.f` and `p.f` was in global scope because it was never declared with `var`.

Comment: That will *change* things, but now that callback function will have access to *neither* of those variables.

Comment: Not true, that confuses scope with context.  Using var makes x within the local scope refer to x in the global context (window).  Using this.x refers to x within the context of whatever object "this" is.

Comment: That is incorrect. A `var` declaration inside a function creates a variable that is local to that function.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say *not* using var makes x within the local scope refer to x in the global context.  You are correct that using var x creates a variable local to that function (with no context).

Answer (score 1):

The variable "x" is **global**, because it's not declared explicitly with `var`. Thus all of those functions reference the same "x".

Object properties in JavaScript must always be explicitly referenced as such. That is, unlike languages like C++ or Java, JavaScript provides for no implicit references to "member variables". If you want a property "x" on those objects, you'll have to refer to it as `this.x`.

Comment: That would give the desired output in this example. It's a slightly different behavior from what I intended.  this.x would always refer to o.x while var x would be a different variable each time o.f() gets called.